# Salto de Linea en una Lista, Comprehension List Python 3.8.0

Tags: python-3.x, salto-de-linea

Hice un script que:

1. Se conecta a un servicio financiero mediante su API y recoge valores de acciones, monedas, etc.
2. Si determinada acción o valor baja más de un 3 % salta una alerta.
3. Si salta la alerta se conecta a un servicio de noticias financieras con otra API y devuelve los tres artículos primeros relacionados con dicha acción, empresa, valor.

Todo funciona pero cuando me da el resultado final me da toda la lista en un bloque.
¿Cómo puedo obtener un resultado mas legible donde cada concepto se presente en una línea diferente?.

Pongo el trozo de código que me da el problema. Mirad yo tengo esto:

```
    if dif_percent > 3:
        print("ALERTA... leer la prensa")
        news_params = {
            "apiKey": NEWS_APIKEY,
            "qInTitle": COMPANY_NAME,
        }
        news_response = requests.get(NEWS_ENDPOINT, params= news_params)
        articles = news_response.json()["articles"]
        three_articles = articles[:3]
        formatted_article = [f"Titular:{article['title']}. \nResumen Noticia:{article['description']}. \nWeb: 
 {article['url']}" for article in three_articles]
    
    print(formatted_article)
```

Como veis en la penúltima línea he puesto mi salto de carro \n, pero me da este resultado:

TESLA

Ayer 704.7400

Antes de Ayer 738.2000

Diferencia -33.460000000000036 USD$

Diferencia porcentual -5

ALERTA, leer la prensa:

['Titular:Tesla, Inc. 2021 Q1 - Results - Earnings Call Presentation. \nResumen:The following slide deck was published by Tesla, Inc.. \nWeb:https://seekingalpha.com/article/4421440-tesla-inc-2021-q1-results-earnings-call-presentation?source=feed_all_articles', "Titular:Tesla, Inc.'s (TSLA) CEO Elon Musk on Q1 2021 Results - Earnings Call Transcript. \nResumen:Tesla, Inc. (NASDAQ:TSLA) Q1 2021 Earnings Conference Call April 26, 2021 5:30 PM ETCompany ParticipantsMartin Viecha - Senior Director, Investor RelationsElon Musk - Chief Executive.... \nWeb:https://seekingalpha.com/article/4421439-tesla-inc-s-tsla-ceo-elon-musk-on-q1-2021-results-earnings-call-transcript?source=feed_all_articles", 'Titular:Was The Smart Money Right About Piling Into Tesla Inc. (TSLA)?. \nResumen:The financial regulations require hedge funds and wealthy investors that exceeded the $100 million holdings threshold
to file a report that shows their.... \nWeb:https://finance.yahoo.com/news/smart-money-piling-tesla-inc-141938791.html']

¿Veis ese "leer prensa"? sale en un bloque entero difícil de leer...  yo deseo algo mas claro tipo:

Titular:*******

Resumen Noticia:*****

Web:*******

(tres veces ya que a la API le he solicitado solo las tres primeras noticias)

He intentado solucionarlo de varias maneras, pero no doy con la clave en mi código y cuando busco info mayoritariamente me remiten a la expresión \n....que ya la tengo puesta. Así que no se...:-?

Espero haberme explicado. No se si me podéis ayudar, cualquier consejo, ejemplo o info será estupendo.

Gracias Mil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado está saliendo como lo esperado, pero en formato lista. Como estás imprimiendo una lista, Python muestra las cadenas junto con sus caracteres de escape.

Si quieres imprimir la cadena resultante de esa lista, hay que hacer una conversión de lista a cadena, haciendo concatenación de elementos. Hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero la más pythonica que conozco es `''.join(lista)`

```
print(''.join(formatted_article))
```

Da como resultado:

```
Titular:Tesla, Inc. 2021 Q1 - Results - Earnings Call Presentation.
Resumen:The following slide deck was published by Tesla, Inc..
Web:https://seekingalpha.com/article/4421440-tesla-inc-2021-q1-results...
...
```

Comment: Esa era la palabra **conversión de lista a cadena**, Si. Ahora si tiene la salida que deseaba. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el error está en que el salto de línea no está haciéndose efectivo.

Si pruebas en el intérprete Python lo siguiente

```
a = ["hola\nprobando"]
print(a)
```

el resultado es

```
['hola\nprobando']
```

Por tanto, hay que hacer el salto de línea de otra forma, por ejemplo utilizando varias veces `print()`:

```
if dif_percent > 3:
    print("ALERTA... leer la prensa")
    news_params = {
        "apiKey": NEWS_APIKEY,
        "qInTitle": COMPANY_NAME,
    }
    news_response = requests.get(NEWS_ENDPOINT, params= news_params)
    articles = news_response.json()["articles"]
    for i in range(len(articles)):
        print("Titular: ", articles[i]['title'], ".", sep="")
        print("Resumen Noticia: ", articles[i]['description'], ".", sep="")
        print("Web: ", articles[i]['url'], ".", sep="")
```

Comment: Estaba tan obcecado que no vi tu solución. Es inteligente, y fácil pero prefiero la  propuesta de @aeportugal en una sola linea. Gracias

Comment: Me alegro de que se haya solucionado. Un saludo.